# D5000 is changing random colors in photos

Tags: nikon, troubleshooting, color, nikon-d5000

My Nikon D5000 started changing random parts of my photos to blue and purple while I was at a equestrian show. I originally suspected that the CCD had started to fail. However, I just replaced the sensor in the camera, and I am still getting the same result. I have tried different cards and updated the camera's firmware. I'm not sure what could be causing this.

[image]

[image]

The second picture shows the same snapshot taken with my D7100.

Comment: Is this a JPG or a RAW file?  If JPG, do the RAW files have the same problem?

Comment: Yes, the JPG and RAW files both look this way. I also noticed while focusing in live view the color distortion isn't present, but it returns once the camera locks focus.

Comment: !!!??? Ouch, Whoever replaced the sensor should have fixed the problem, not just replace one part and not fixing it.

Comment: Do you have another photo of this scene (taken with a different camera) that can show us what the colors are supposed to look like?

Comment: I added a second photo of the same window.

Comment: Did _you_ replace the sensor, or did a service center?

Comment: A local shop that I have been using for a few years did the replacement for me. The shop owner did not charge me for the replacement since it didn't fix the issue.

Comment: Yep, you just had me thinking "If he is capable of replacing a sensor without making things worse, he probably knows more than we do already" :)

Comment: And btw, I would suspect the problem somewhere in the camera-internal power supply/biasing circuitry supplying the sensor... or maybe something with the signal conditioning circuitry ... anything else would likely give no image at all or crash the camera...

Comment: What do the histograms for each colour channel look like?  It's almost like one is partially or completely missing (or drastically shifted).

Comment: Thank you all for your replies! This morning I decided to take another round of test photos on the D5000 and it took flawless photos. I honestly don't have an explanation for why this happened. I left it on my desk without changing anything. Anyways, thanks again for constructive feedback.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you didn't by accident change any settings in the camera's Retouch Menu?

[image]

This looks like extreme posterization or reversed color outline applied by in-camera "artistic" filters.

Check out this video at 3m:41s mark: https://youtu.be/eRd6o9MyI50